# Facebook image button is stretched

Tags: android, facebook, button

I use the following XML for sharing on Facebook in my app. for a reason it shows up stretched.

**XML**:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/fbShareButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_button_icon_blue"
         />
```

[Stretched facebook image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk7Dm.png)

How can I make it look in a normal size ?

Comment: Because you set the image as a background of `Button`. Try by replacing `Button` with `ImageButton` and set `android:src="@drawable/com_facebook_button_icon_blue"`

Comment: can you share your full XMLcode?

Comment: Followed your suggestion and it shows perfect, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an imageButton:

```
<ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/fbShareButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:src="@drawable/com_facebook_button_icon_blue"
                        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove weight from layout and provide width to "wrap_content".

Answer (score 0):

Remove   `android:layout_weight="1"`and give `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

it will work surely:-

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/fbShareButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_button_icon_blue"
         />
```